# Marking imprecise durations in recipe microdata

Tags: schema.org, duration, microdata, rich-snippets, recipe

It's easy to markup a recipe's cooking or [preparation time](http://schema.org/prepTime) if it's for a specific time range:

```
Prep time: <time datetime="PT30M" itemprop="prepTime">30 min</time>
Cook time: <time datetime="PT1H" itemprop="cookTime">1 hour</time>
```

However, many recipes use estimated durations instead:

```
Prep time: 10-30 minutes
Cook time: 1 - 1½ hours
```

What's the best way of marking this information up in a way [that'll be picked up by Google?](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/recipes) From what I can tell, the [ISO 8601 duration format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) doesn't seem to support "fuzzy" durations/duration ranges.

It's tempting to interpolate the time range so the machine-readable value sits halfway between the human-readable min/max values:

```
Prep time: <time datetime="PT20M" itemprop="prepTime">10-30 minutes</time>

Humans see:           10-30 minutes
Google/machines see:  20 minutes
```

That feels hacky and forced, though, and also feels like I'm feeding search engines incorrect data with specifics for the sake of SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** I don’t think the `time` element as currently specified provides any good way to specify “fuzzy” durations.

**Longer answer**

This is by design a known issue/limitation in the current definition of the `time` element in the HTML spec. There’s been discussion about it, and some proposals for extending the scope of `time` to address that use case; see https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Time_element#Fuzzy_dates

The proposal that’s had the most traction is to add a `certainty` attribute to `time` that would allow you to do something like this:

```
Prep time: <time datetime="PT20M" certainty="10M">10-30 minutes</time>
```

Along with that `certainty`-attribute idea, there’s also been discussion of updating the specs for actual time formats to include a way to use `?` or `~` characters to specify approximations; see http://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/pre-submission.html#uncertain

Anyway, there’s not yet been agreement about any of the proposed solutions, so gist of it remains that there’s unfortunately not yet any standard way to express a fuzzy duration—and I think also not really even any very good workarounds other than the one mentioned in the question.

Comment: Bugger. :( *sigh* Alright, thanks, mate... very informative answer. Guess I'll have to improvise, heh. Cheers!

Comment: Cheers. If you feel strongly about the need for this, you could consider e-mailing `whatwg.org@whatwg.org` to see if you might be able to rally some other people interested in moving forward with getting `certainty` into the HTML spec. Or file a bug report at https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/enter_bug.cgi?product=WHATWG&component=HTML. (We’ll hopefully soon have a way you can raise issues at against the HTML spec through a github issue tracker, but we’re not there yet.)

Comment: ISO/W3 standards are holy law for me, I'd be honoured.

Comment: @Alhadis You can also extend the HTML microdata vocabulary, for example,  https://github.com/guest271314/Definition , https://github.com/guest271314/Excerpt